# Symfony2 Assetic dump when using multiple kernels

Tags: php, symfony, kernel, assets, assetic

Using Symfony 2.7. I made my application in multiple kernels. My folder structure is like this:

```
Project
 |   
 +-- app/
 |  |  
 |  +-- candy/    // all config, parameters, kernel for candy application
 |  +-- vegetable/  // all config, parameters, kernel for vegetable application
 |    
 +-- src/ 
 +-- bin/
 +-- vendor/
 |  
 +-- web/
    |
    +-- candy/  // all assets, images, js etc. for candy application
    +-- vegetable/ // all assets, images, js etc. for vegetable application
```

Now when I want to install assets i simply do:

```
php app/candy/console assets:install web/candy/
```

this works, however when I do:

```
php app/candy/console assetic:dump web/candy/
```

it searches for files in `web/` directory, not in  `web/candy/bundles/../`.

Why is that and what can be the solutions?

My base.html.twig:

```
{% block stylesheets %}
    {% stylesheets
    'bundles/mpshop/css/jquery-ui.css'
    'bundles/mpshop/css/bootstrap.min.css'
    'bundles/mpshop/css/style.css'
    'bundles/mpshop/css/docs.css'
    'bundles/mpshop/css/lightbox.css'
    'bundles/mpshop/css/bootstrap-select.css'
    'bundles/mpshop/css/style_custom.css'
    'bundles/mpshop/css/responsive.css'
    'bundles/mpshop/slick/slick.css'
    'bundles/mpshop/slick/slick-theme.css'
    'bundles/mpshop/css/fonts_googleapis.css'
    filter='cssrewrite'
    %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />

    {% endstylesheets %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
{% endblock %}

{% block javascripts %}
    {% javascripts
    'bundles/mpshop/js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js'
    'bundles/mpshop/js/jquery-ui.js'
    'bundles/mpshop/js/migrate.js'
    'bundles/mpshop/js/bootstrap.min.js'
    'bundles/mpshop/js/bootstrap-select.js'
    'bundles/mpshop/js/search.js'
    'bundles/mpshop/js/ckeditor.js'
    'bundles/mpshop/js/jquery.lightbox-0.5.js'
    'bundles/mpshop/js/lightbox.js'
    'bundles/mpshop/slick/slick.js'
    'bundles/mpshop/js/custom.js'
    'bundles/mpshop/js/scroll-to-top.js'
    'bundles/mpshop/js/jquery.smooth_scroll.js'
    %}
    <script src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
    {% endjavascripts %}
```

config.yml:

```
assetic:
    debug:          "%kernel.debug%"
    use_controller: "%kernel.debug%"
    bundles:        [ EDBlogBundle, ApplicationEDBlogBundle ]
    #java: /usr/bin/java
    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the "write_to" directory in the config for each kernel.

<kbd>app/candy/config/config.yml</kbd>

```
assetic:
    //...
    write_to:             '%kernel.root_dir%/../../web/candy'
```

<kbd>app/vegetable/config/config.yml</kbd>

```
assetic:
    //...
    write_to:             '%kernel.root_dir%/../../web/vegetable'
```

*Just as a side note*, why is it that you are using multiple kernels?
I've heard the possibility of it but never seen the benefits so am interested in the thinking.

Comment: Aaaand it works! I am using multiple kernels for managing multiple aplications in one project that will use same database structure and mostly same functionality, but will have different templates and data.. So for example two different domains under one host www.car.com and www.phone.com is actually the same thing except different templates and some other parameters

Comment: Glad it works. Fair enough with the kernels.. I've not hit that particular use case yet so have no had to find a way of dealing with it.